# Same error check for multiple inputs with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to perform an error check on the `keyup` event. I want to avoid having to write the same code for each input. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(function(){

    var Regex     =  /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;
    var selector  = [$('#username'),$('#password')];
    var container = $('.error');

    $.each(selector).keyup(function() {
        if(selector.val().length<=4 || selector.val().length>10) {
            $(container).remove();
            $(this).after('<span class="'+container+'">"The '+selector+' must contain a minimum of 4 characters and a maximum of 10"</span>');
        } else if(!Regex.test(selector)) {
            $(container).remove();
            $(this).after('<span class="error '+container+'">"The '+selector+' must contain letters and numbers only"</span>');
        } else {
            $(this).after('<span class="good '+container+'">Looks good</span>');
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**
After some modifications to the code, this is what I got, and it is working perfectly:

```
$(function(){

var Regex     =  /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;
var container = $('.input-error');

$(".inputs").keyup(function(e){

        var input_content = $(this).val();
        var input_name    = $(this).attr("name");       

        if(input_content.length<=4 || input_content.length>10){

            $('.input-error').remove();
            $(this).after('<span class="error input-error">"The '+input_name+' must contain a minimum of 4 characters and a maximum of 10"</span>');

        }else if(!Regex.test(input_content)){

            $('.input-error').remove();
            $(this).after('<span class="error input-error">"The '+input_name+' must contain letters and numbers only"</span>');

        }else{
            $('.input-error').remove();
            $('.input-error').addClass("good");
            $(this).after('<span class="good input-error">"Looks Good"</span>');
        }

});
});
```

Thanks for the help...

Comment: Just use a common class on your inputs... `$(".myClass").keyup(function() {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a common class on your elements - so you can write one selector:

```
<input type="text" class="required-input" />
<input type="text" class="required-input" />
```

JS:

```
var Regex     =  /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;
var errorClass = "error";

$(".required-input").keyup(function(e) {
    //$(this) refers to the element having the current keyup action

    if(this.value.length<=4 || this.value.length>10) {
        $(this).next("." + errorClass).remove();
        $(this).after('<span class="'+errorClass +'">"The input must contain a minimum of 4 characters and a maximum of 10"</span>');
    } else if(!Regex.test(this.value)) {
        $(this).next("." + errorClass).remove();
        $(this).after('<span class="error '+errorClass+'">"The input must contain letters and numbers only"</span>');
    } else {
        $(this).after('<span class="good ' + errorClass + '">Looks good</span>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Got your idea and after a few changes worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using it like this

```
var selector  = [$('#username'),$('#password')];
```

simply give your input fields a class and use it like that:

```
   $('.inputclass').keyup(function() { 
        // ... code to execute comes here
```

This will target all input fields with the class (in this case) inputclass.